# Kendo Ui Mobile ModalView

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui Mobile ModalView in my aspx page but i am unable to get the required output.On click of button it is showing the same page. I am new to Kendo ui. Please anyone help me.please refer kendo ui mobile modal view and suggest me how to use it in my project.

```
My code is
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<link href="CSS/kendo.common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<%--<link href="CSS/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />--%>
<link href="CSS/kendo.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/kendo.mobile.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="CSS/Example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="Js/jquery1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="CSS/kendo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function closeModalViewLogin() {
    $("#modalview-login").data("kendoModalView").open();
}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
</script>
</head>

 <body>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div data-role="view" id="modalview-camera" data-title="HTML5 Camera">
<img src="../../content/mobile/modalview/lens.png" class="camera-image" /><br />
<a data-role="button" data-rel="modalview" href="#modalview-login" id="modalview-open-  
button">Login</a>
</div>


<div data-role="modalview" id="modalview-login" style="width: 95%; height: 80%;">
<div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <span>Login</span>
        <a data-click="closeModalViewLogin" data-role="button" data- 
align="right">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
    <li><label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text" id="username" />  


</li>
    <li><label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password" />  
</li>
</ul>
<a data-click="closeModalViewLogin" id="modalview-login-button" type="button" data-  
role="button">Login</a>
<a data-click="closeModalViewLogin" id="modalview-reg-button" type="button" data-  
role="button">Register</a>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example of the code you have used as starting point @ http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/modalview/index.html - you will find out that position of script tags with calls to Kendo framework are located at the bottom of the body tag, if you place them above the body as is shown in your example code, at that stage there is nothing to execute the script on. You need to move them at the correct place. Alternatively use jQuery ready command and call Kendo scripts from there.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can initialize the mobile application on the form, instead of the body, since the Views should be direct descendants of the application element.

Answer (score 0):

**Change code as per requirements**

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Model view sample</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.710/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closeModalViewLogin() {
            $("#modalview-login").data("kendoModalView").open();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="view" id="modalview-camera" data-title="HTML5 Camera">
        <a data-role="button" data-rel="modalview" href="#modalview-login" id="modalview-open-button">Login</a>

        <div data-role="modalview" id="modalview-login" style="width: 95%; height: 80%;">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <span>Login</span>
                    <a data-click="closeModalViewLogin" data-role="button" data-align="right">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
                <li>
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" />


                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a data-click="closeModalViewLogin" id="modalview-login-button" data-role="button">Login</a>
            <a data-click="closeModalViewLogin" id="modalview-reg-button" data-role="button">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine.

**Note**

1: Model view should always use within `<div data-role="view" ...>...</div>`

2: Intialize kendo mobile application after document to be ready
(i.e var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body))

Comment: According to the demo you're wrong about your first note, the modal-view is not inside a <div data-role="view"></div> http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/modalview/index.html